# Документирование Python

Tags: python

по советуйте что-то простое (Sphinx не предлагать) для генерации документации, дабы не тратить много времени на изучение. Получается я использовал Pydoc, но там походу нельзя документировать свойства класса и поэтому мне преподаватель сказал взять что-то другое, которое сможет это сделать. Если помимо модуля покажете, как оформлять (функции, классы, свойства класса) - буду бесконечно благодарен.
Вот отрывок класса для примера как это выглядит сейчас.

```
class Calc:
    """
    Класс калькулятора
    """
    system_number1 = 0
    number1 = 0
    system_number2 = 0
    number2 = 0
    system_result = 0
    result = 0
    operation = ''
    low = 2
    high = 37
    textForSystem = "Введите систему счисления(2 - 36): "
    errorForSystem = "Некорректный ввод! Введите число в диапазоне от 2 до 36"
    textForNum = "Введите число: "
    errorForNum = "Некорректный ввод! Введите число входящее в систему счисления: "
    textForOper = "Введите оперцию (+,-,*,/): "
    errorForOper = "Некорректный ввод! Введите одну из преложенных операций. "
    errorDivide = "Некорректный ввод!Нельзя делить на 0."
    resutText = "Ответ: "
    operationArr = ['+','-','*','/']
    def check_sys(self,response):
        """
        Проверяет введенную систему счисления
        """
        try:
           if int(response) not in  range(self.low,self.high):
               return False
           else:
               return True
        except ValueError:
           return False
```

Comment: почему не опишешь атрибуты в тексте документации класса как это делают в numpy например?